# Restructuring Json using Golang

Tags: arrays, json, go, struct

I have the following JSON response:

```
[
      {
        "talent_id": "b520ad50-5302-45ce-9121-5ff42d67b4fb",
        "platform": "facebook",
        "posts": [
          {
            "insights": [
              {
                "name": "post_impressions_organic_unique",
                "values": [
                  {
                    "value": 1828
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "name": "post_stories_by_action_type",
                "values": [
                  {
                    "like": 42
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "type": "photo",
            "post_id": "24225267232_10154099759037233"
          },
          {
            "insights": [
              {
                "name": "post_impressions_organic_unique",
                "values": [
                  {
                    "value": 864
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "name": "post_stories_by_action_type",
                "values": [
                  {
                    "like": 19
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "type": "photo",
            "post_id": "24225267232_10154099756677233"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I need to restructure/flatten it into something like this:

```
{
    "talent_id": "b520ad50-5302-45ce-9121-5ff42d67b4fb",
    "platform": "facebook",
    "posts": [{
        "post_id": "24225267232_10154051404062233",
        "type": "photo",
        "organic_impressions_unique": 8288,
        "post_story_actions_by_type": {
            "shares": 234,
            "comments": 838,
            "likes": 8768
        }
    }, {
        "post_id": "24225267232_10154051404062233",
        "type": "photo",
        "organic_impressions_unique": 8288,
        "post_story_actions_by_type": {
            "shares": 234,
            "comments": 838,
            "likes": 8768
        }
    }]
}
```

I am using a struct to map the JSON response:

```
type JsonData struct {
    TalentID string `json:"talent_id"`
    Platform string `json:"platform"`
    Posts []struct {
        PostID string `json:"post_id"`
        Type string `json:"type"`
        Insights []struct {
            //Data []map[string]interface{}
            Name   string `json:"name"`
        } `json:"insights"`
    } `json:"posts"`
}
```

My problem is with the data inside the posts and how can I map it, I am using a map to fill the data and Marshal it to generate the new structure of JSON.

Here is my code:

```
    messages := [] JsonData{}
    json.Unmarshal(body, &messages)

    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    m["talent_id"] = messages[0].TalentID
    m["platform"] = messages[0].Platform

    for _, p := range messages[0].Posts {

        for _, i := range p.Insights {
            // here is where I got lost and couldn't know how to fill the data inside the posts
        }
    }


    jsonString, err := json.Marshal(m)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(jsonString))
```

P.S. the metrics post_impressions_organic_unique and post_stories_by_action_type are not static, they can change or other keys might be returned here

Comment: Why aren't you simply running a marshal on the struct object? That would work and since you've provided runes, it will properly convert it to JSON.

Comment: it won't work, since I don't know what will be filled inside the `Insights []struct `

Comment: Yeah, so simply define a `[]map[string]interface` in the struct. It'll take care of everything on its own. Make it like `Insights []map[string]interface{}`

Comment: if you're not even sure it'll be an array of something, then simply put an `interface{}` there.

Comment: not working with interface{}, error: unexpected interface, expecting field name or embedded type

Comment: should I make it `Data interface{}` for example?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the missing Data

Comment: @ishaan this won't work buddy, the generated json will be like this: `"posts": [{
  "post_id": "24225267232_10154099759037233",
  "type": "photo",
  "insights": [{
   "name": "post_impressions_organic_unique",
   "values": [{
    "value": 1828
   }]
  }`

Comment: I need it to be something else like `organic_impressions_unique": 8288 ` without the name parameter

Answer (score 0):

Keep your struct as:

```
type NameValue struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Values []map[string]interface{} `json:"values"`
}

type JsonData struct {
    TalentID string `json:"talent_id"`
    Platform string `json:"platform"`
    Posts []struct {
        PostID string `json:"post_id"`
        Type string `json:"type"`
        Insights []NameValue `json:"insights"`
    } `json:"posts"`
}
```

Create another struct similar to this one:

```
type JsonDataRes struct {
    TalentID string `json:"talent_id"`
    Platform string `json:"platform"`
    Posts []map[string]interface{} `json:"posts"`
}
```

Once you have the data in your `JsonData` struct, loop over the insights object and manually assign values to the new `JsonDataRes` object and also the vaules of `PostId` and `Type` inside the Posts `[]map[string]interface{}`

Comment: it is not working while doing so: 
`for _, p := range messages[0].Posts {
        for k, i := range p.Insights {
            jsonRes.Posts["post_id"] = p.PostID
            fmt.Println(i)
            fmt.Println(k)
        }
    }`

Comment: and this won't work as well:  `for _, p := range messages[0].Posts {
        for k, i := range p.Insights {
            jsonRes.Posts[k]["post_id"] = p.PostID
            fmt.Println(i)
            fmt.Println(k)
        }
    }`

the difference is this `jsonRes.Posts[k]`